# Borrowing the T in a Rc<RefCell<T>>

Tags: rust, borrowing

I'm trying to do something like this

```
use std::cell::{RefCell,Ref,RefMut};
use std::rc::Rc;

struct Entity;

struct Tile {
    entity: Option<Rc<RefCell<Entity>>>
}

impl Tile {
    pub fn try_read_entity<'a>(&'a self) -> Option<Ref<'a, Entity>> {
        self.entity.map(|e| e.borrow())
    }
}
```

I'm getting lifetime related errors and find it difficult to understand what exactly is going wrong, or whether it's even possible to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the signature of the `Option::map()` method:

```
fn map<U, F>(self, f: F) -> Option<U>
    where F: FnOnce(T) -> U
```

`self` means that `map()` takes the option *by value*, that is, it consumes it. In particular it means moving the option value out from its previous place. But you can't do it because in your code you take `self` by reference - you cannot move from out of a reference, and that's exactly what error is about.

However, you don't need to consume the option, you only need a reference to its contained value. Fortunately, `Option<T>` provides a method, `fn as_ref(&'a self) -> Option<&'a T>`, which can be used to obtain a reference to internals of an option. If you just call it prior to calling `map()`, your code will work:

```
self.entity.as_ref().map(|e| e.borrow())
```